# VB.NET Cross platform app

Tags: vb.net

I make a game using vb.net & wpf. But I want this run on Windows/Linux/Mac.
How can I do it?
I'm sorry my english is really bad :D I use Google translate.

Comment: WPF is a Windows-only GUI framework. You will need to rewrite your game if you want to take it to other platforms.

Comment: This website is for code specific problems.  Have you made a game and have an error on one of those platforms?  [please see google otherwise](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb.net+cross+platform)

Comment: Hmm, ok. My game is Webmaster Tycoon.

Comment: @BerkenUsar That doesn't really tell us anything (and yes, I looked for your game by that name on Google and could not find it there either). We can only effectively help you if you can provide a [mcve] for your specific question, but this seems really broad as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a solution for multiple platforms is not an easy task and you need to be familiar with all the platforms you plan to support, starting with trivialities such as different path schemes and ending with checking every reference you require by your project settings for its compatibility to the target platform.

Please have a look at http://www.mono-project.com. When you install the mono package to your system, you can run your compiled .exe as it is from the shell under certain circumstances.

Obviously, you need to decide whether you try to create one application that runs on all target platforms OR if you want to create platform specific applications all referencing to the same game engine.

If you stick very close to the framework not using external references, chances are higher to achieve the former. If the main logic of your game can easily be compartmentalized into a dedicated project, the latter is the way to go.

In general, cross-plattform compatibility is more easily to achieve if your application backend consists of a console application to be accessed by a webbrowser installed on the system - using a web frontend though. But as long as you do not require accelerated graphics, this should be feasible.